# VB - MySql select from a database

Tags: mysql, vb.net

This is how my form looks like - [image](http://www.mupload.nl/img/9fjcditrdop.png).

When form loads, I would like to retrieve the player data whose `username` is in the `Label1`, so I could display its `points` in the `Label2`.

Here's my code so far:

```
Dim conn As MySqlConnection
conn = New MySqlConnection("server=REMOVED;Port=REMOVED; user id=REMOVED; password=REMOVED; database=REMOVED")
Dim username As Boolean = True
conn.Open()
Dim sqlquery As String = "SELECT Name FROM NewTable WERE Name='" & My.Settings.Name & "';"
Dim data As MySqlDataReader
Dim adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
Dim command As New MySqlCommand
command.CommandText = sqlquery
command.Connection = conn
adapter.SelectCommand = command
data = command.ExecuteReader
While data.Read()
    Label1.Text = data(1).ToString
    Label2.Text = data(3).ToString
End While

data.Close()
conn.Close()
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should parameterized your query to avoid sql injection,  `Using` for proper object disposal, `Try-Catch` block to handle the exception properly.

```
Dim connString As String = "server=REMOVED;Port=REMOVED; user id=REMOVED; password=REMOVED; database=REMOVED"
Dim sqlQuery As String = "SELECT Name, Points FROM NewTable WHERE Name = @uname"
Using sqlConn As New MySqlConnection(connString)
    Using sqlComm As New MySqlCommand()
        With sqlComm
            .Connection = sqlConn
            .Commandtext = sqlQuery
            .CommandType = CommandType.Text
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", My.Settings.Name)
        End With
        Try
            sqlConn.Open()
            Dim sqlReader As MySqlDataReader = sqlComm.ExecuteReader()
            While sqlReader.Read()
                Label1.Text = sqlReader("Name").ToString()
                Label2.Text = sqlReader("Points").ToString()
            End While
        Catch ex As MySQLException
            ' add your exception here '
        End Try
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: Thank you realy much for helping me. this is my second day using mysql and vb togheter. :D